# How to round off <type 'float> number to its nearest integer/whole number in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, numbers

I have  Variable as Follows:

```
num1 = 491597.379188893
num2 = -17.5438596491228
num3 = 327.480916030534
num4 = 11258.1848115617
```

**How can I round off this numbers to whole numbers giving its values as:**

```
num1 = 491597
num2 = -18
num3 = 327
num4 = 11258
```

I am using round(number) function which is giving not giving me expected output.

**My code looks Like This:**

```
Difference = (Current_UID - Previous_UID) 
Difference /= Previous_UID
Difference *= 100
round(timeDifference)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the rounded number back to the variable.

```
Difference = round(Difference)
```

Comment: Damn i actually missed the core logical part. Thanks a lot!